# How to build a structure against cloning on NTAG 21x or Desfire

Tags: android, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to figure out a viable way to build a secure structure against cloning on NTAG 21x family or Desfire.

I had been researching, and it seem like both arent good for a secure system. But many metro cards/transport NFC cards etc are build on it, so i am trying to understand why.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite&hl=en
NFC taginfo app can reveal the password protected area's data.

Card ID can be cloned by emulator....

So does it mean everything can be read and cloned onto a replica card. So i am trying to figure out a structure that will not allow a person to replicate a card.

Does anyone has experience in this area??

Even with encrypted Card id and content, if someone clone the whole thing, and when the server tries to decrypt it, it wont be able to tell if the card is a replica, but how does the metro/train company put security inplace???

Comment: Why can't Desfire be "good" for a secure system? As far as I know, its security is much better than for Mifare Classic.

Comment: Hi, yer i was debating with myself about if NTAG 21x is safe enough, and it seemed that the password protected area isnt save enough, and i should be choosing the 3DES/AES protection instead of NTAG21x, but just the cost is drastically higher...... another part is i dont need that much memory, less than 1k, so i wasnt sure if the Ultralight EV1 protection is to the same level as Desfire or not....

Comment: Mifare Ultralight main point seems to be its low cost, not its security features. You can set some bytes to make it read-only, but that will not keep anyone for cloning the card; Mifare Desfire is much better, since you can set it to require mutual authentication with the reader. 
Depending on your requirements, if cost is critical you can implement some protection measure, like a MAC using a key derived from each card's UID.